# How to insert small int values to NumberLong in document DB / mongo DB by using python/pymongo

Tags: pymongo, long-integer, python-3.9, aws-documentdb

When we are trying to insert small integer values let's say 45 to documentDB.
It's been saved as just an integer/Number value in documentDB.

But I want that to be saved as NumberLong irrespective of the value whether it's small or long.

I have tried adding
`{"$numberLong": str(int_value)}`

But getting exceptions while inserting to document DB.
`Document can't have $ prefix field names: $numberLong`

I am using insert_many() as I have to save an array of records.

Comment: Do you have success with [`bson.int64.Int64`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/int64.html)?